# populating extra field with woocommerce categories

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

i have wordpress with woocommerce + dokan marketplace plugin.
in dokan shop settings i would add a category dropdown field. in my function.php:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'dokan_settings_form_bottom', 'extra_fields_cat', 10, 2);
function extra_fields_cat( $current_user, $profile_info ){
$cat_shop= isset( $profile_info['cat_shop'] ) ? $profile_info['cat_shop'] : ''; ?>
<div>
<?php (isset($_POST["category1"])) ? $company = $_POST["category1"] : $company=1; ?>
<select name="cat_shop" id="reg_cat_shop" class="dokan-form-control input-md valid" >
<option <?php if ($cat_shop == 'category1' ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="category1">category1</option>
<option <?php if ($cat_shop == 'category2' ) echo 'selected' ; ?> value="category2">category2</option>
</select></div>
<?php }
//save the field value
add_action( 'dokan_store_profile_saved', 'save_extra_fields_cat', 15 );
function save_extra_fields_cat( $store_id ) {
$dokan_settings = dokan_get_store_info($store_id);
if ( isset( $_POST['cat_shop'] ) ) {
$dokan_settings['cat_shop'] = $_POST['cat_shop'];
}
update_user_meta( $store_id, 'dokan_profile_settings', $dokan_settings );
}
```

this example works correctly, but i want populate this field with a woocommerce categories.
is it possible in some way?
thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, solution:

```
$args = array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' =>'-1'
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
 (isset($_POST["Cianfrusaglie"])) ? $company = $_POST["Cianfrusaglie"] : $company=1;

echo "<select name='cat_shop' id='reg_cat_shop' class='dokan-form-control input-md valid'>";
foreach( $product_categories as $category ){
    echo "<option "; ?><?php if ($cat_shop == esc_html( $category->name ) ) echo 'selected' ; ?>
    <?php echo "value = '" . esc_attr( $category->name ) . "'>" . esc_html( $category->name ) . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Now, in my woocommerce new product page, how i can select my category?